# Java global int

Tags: java, android-studio

In an Android Studio app, I have following code:

```
    boolean clicked = true;
    Button btnumb1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.numb1);
    Button btnumb2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.numb2);
    Button btnumb3 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.numb3);
    Button btnumb4 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.numb4);
    btnumb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked = false;
        }
    });

    Button Start = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.Start);
    Start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (clicked == false) {
                Random rand = new Random();
                int n = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.randOutput);
                textView.setText("" + n);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have to choose a number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

The idea is that when one of the 4 buttons is clicked, the int clicked is set to 1 and so the final button can only be clicked when it is 1.
But the code doesn't work like this; int clicked = 0; can't be accessed in other public void.
[If one of the numbers 1,2,3,4 is clicked then final button can be clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM7vw.png)

Comment: make it final or global. Both will work .You are not making clicked global . i think it is inside oncreate method.

Comment: ... with ```final``` being the preferred way. You might also want to consider ```boolean``` instead of ```int``` for that scenario.

Comment: @Surace when I apply final: Error:(43, 17) error: cannot assign a value to final variable clicked

Comment: Yes . final variable cant change that's why you are getting this kind of error .

Comment: But that is the point, I want to change the value and when I assign global: Error:(34, 9) error: not a statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix: Put `public static boolean clicked = false;`

under your `public class YourClassName {` line.

Reasoning: You need to learn how to scope your variables properly. You declared boolean clicked inside the `onCreate()` function, so the variable is gone after `onCreate()` is done running.

You should have put the `clicked` variable inside the class scope level, via `public boolean clicked` or `public static boolean clicked` so that even after the function returns, the value is saved.

I highly recommend a beginners java course or textbook before continuing on with your project(s).

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have any concept of global variables. There is either an instance variable or a class variable. To define Global Variable you can make use of static Keyword.

```
static boolean clicked = true;
Button btnumb1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.numb1);
Button btnumb2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.numb2);
Button btnumb3 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.numb3);
Button btnumb4 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.numb4);
btnumb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clicked = false;
    }
});

Button Start = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.Start);
Start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (clicked == false) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int n = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.randOutput);
            textView.setText("" + n);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have to choose a number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes the variable int clicked = 0; has to be declared final before it is accessible in the other public void functions.

Try this declared a class say ClassClicked

```
public class ClassClicked {
    int clicked;

    public int getClicked() {
        return clicked;
    }

    public void setClicked(int clicked) {
        this.clicked = clicked;
    }

}
```

Then changed

```
int clicked = 0;
```

to

```
final ClassClicked clicked = new ClassClicked();
clicked.setClicked(0);
```

And

```
clicked = 1;
```

to

```
clicked.setClicked(1);
```

Finally

```
clicked == 1
```

to

```
clicked.getClicked() == 1
```